# trying to install vulkan fails

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, xubuntu, intel-graphics, vulkan

I am trying to install `vulkan` from
https://launchpad.net/%7Ecanonical-x/+archive/ubuntu/vulkan

Everything works fine until entering this line:

```
sudo apt install vulkan-utils mesa-vulkan-drivers
cannot find vulkan-utils
cannot find mesa-vulkan-drivers
```

I am using Xubuntu 14.04 with Intel 3rd gen, does anyone know what's going wrong??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately it looks as if this PPA does not have much joy for Trusty Tahr:

> This ppa contains bits and pieces needed to test Vulkan BUT ONLY FOR XENIAL 
>   (and maybe 14.04 in the future).

If you [filter for Trusty Tahr only](https://launchpad.net/~canonical-x/+archive/ubuntu/vulkan?field.series_filter=trusty) you will see that all that is there for Trusty is the 355 and 364 NVidia drivers.

Comment: wow! I was fearing that! thanks so much for your answer... I'll see what I can do...

Answer (score 1):

Please try it to install first by typing:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:canonical-x/vulkan
sudo apt update
sudo apt install vulkan-utils mesa-vulkan-drivers
```

OutPut:

```
$ sudo apt install vulkan-utils mesa-vulkan-drivers
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer    required:
checkbox-ng gstreamer1.0-clutter iproute libarmadillo5 libarmadillo6 libarpack2
libatk-wrapper-java libatk-wrapper-java-jni libbind9-90 libblas-common libblas3
libcamel-1.2-52 libck-connector0 libcolamd2.8.0 libdap17v5 libdapclient6v5
libdbd-mysql-perl libdbi-perl libdns100 libebook-contacts-1.2-1 libecal-1.2-18
libedata-cal-1.2-27 libedataserver-1.2-20 libepsilon1 libfreexl1 libgdal1i
libglew1.10 libglewmx1.10 libgnutls-deb0-28:i386 libgtop2-10 libimobiledevice4
libisc95 libisccc90 libisccfg90 libisl13 libkmlbase1 libkmldom1 libkmlengine1
liblapack3 libllvm3.6v5 libllvm3.6v5:i386 liblouis2 liblwgeom-2.1.8 liblwres90
libminizip1 libmysqlclient18:i386 libmysqlclient20 libmysqlcppconn7v5
libnetcdf11 libnl-route-3-200 libntdb1 libogdi3.2 libopenjp2-7 libpoppler52
libproj9 libpth20 libqpdf13v5 libraw10 libsctp1 libspatialite7 libsuperlu4
libterm-readkey-perl liburiparser1 libusbmuxd2 libvpx2 libvsqlitepp3v5
linux-headers-4.2.0-16 linux-headers-4.2.0-16-generic linux-headers-4.2.0-36
linux-headers-4.2.0-36-generic linux-image-4.2.0-16-generic
linux-image-4.2.0-36-generic linux-image-extra-4.2.0-16-generic
linux-image-extra-4.2.0-36-generic lksctp-tools mysql-utilities
mysql-workbench-data proj-bin proj-data python-cffi python-characteristic
python-dbus-dev python-mysql.connector python-ntdb python-pexpect python-ply
python-ptyprocess python-pycparser python-pyodbc python-pysqlite2 python3-cffi
python3-checkbox-ng python3-ply python3-pycparser qml-module-qtquick-dialogs
qml-module-qtquick-localstorage qml-module-qtquick-privatewidgets
qtdeclarative5-localstorage-plugin qtdeclarative5-qtfeedback-plugin
qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-web-plugin telepathy-indicator unity-scope-audacious
unity-scope-clementine unity-scope-gmusicbrowser unity-scope-gourmet
unity-scope-guayadeque unity-scope-musique
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
libvulkan1

The following NEW packages will be installed:
libvulkan1 mesa-vulkan-drivers vulkan-utils
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 33 not upgraded.
Need to get 2,988 kB of archives.
After this operation, 15.6 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

it worked for me @ "Ubuntu 16.04" !

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't work for me, i'll try to update my operating system